# Python : Update a changing variable in a window using pygame.font

Tags: python, variables

this is my first post, I'm a begginer in programmation, in Python especially

I created a game with a controllable character, you have to avoid an AI, otherwise the chances decrease each times by 1 (from 10 to 0), I want to print chances in real time, but the problem is that it is displayed twice on top of each other, so we can't see the reamaning chances,I Don't know what to do, I already used **pygame.display.update()**, here's my code's part :

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()

nombreDeFois = 10

font = pygame.font.Font(None, 36)
s = "Chances restantes : " + str(nombreDeFois)
text = font.render(s, 0, (255, 178, 51))
textpos = text.get_rect()
textpos.center = (442,15)
backgroundjeu.blit(text, textpos)

pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack!  I don't see enough details or context to make this a useful question, I'd recommend providing more details.

Comment: Consider adding a [mre]. For example `backgroundjeu` is not defined so we can't run this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you want to display something on the screen with pygame, it gets added to what is already on the screen, so to update it you must first fill the screen with the background color in order to clear the screen and then display it. Generally, this is done every frame for a game with moving graphics.

E.g.:

```py
display = pygame.display.set_mode(...)

#at the start of the code that runs each frame
display.fill(<insert background color>)
```

If you are using a background image, blit it again each frame instead.

This also means that everything needs to be redrawn each frame, though, or it would disappear immediately after the first frame.